# Understanding cuobjdump output

Tags: linux, cuda, gpu, nvcc, ptx

I already [read about virtual architecture and code generation for nvcc](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-steering-gpu-code-generation) but I still have some questions.

I have a cuda compiled executable whose `cuobjdump` output is

```
Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_20
code version = [1,7]
producer = cuda
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit

Fatbin ptx code:
================
arch = sm_20
code version = [5,0]
producer = cuda
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit
compressed
```

I have two questions:

1. What does `code version` mean? Documentation doesn't say that.
2. Would such an executable be compatible on a system with a `sm_30` (Kepler) device? I believe it should because there's PTX code in the executable and the virtual architecture is `sm_20`, i.e. it's asking for a very small set of features available from Fermi cards onward (still not sure what that `code version` means)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. What does code version mean? Documentation doesn't say that.

It means the version of the fatbin element it is printing -- elf version 1.7 and PTX version 5.0 respectively  (see [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#release-notes) for PTX versions)

> 2. Would such an executable be compatible on a system with a sm_30 (Kepler) device?

Yes. The presence of the PTX (version 5.0) means the code can be JIT compiled by the driver to assembler to run on a compute capability 3.0 device (again documentation [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#release-notes))